# Powershell Add_Click code only write-host working

Tags: forms, powershell

```psh
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Mailbox Creation Wizard"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,230) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

#Mailbox new user check
$UserButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$UserButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,70)
$UserButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,23)
$UserButton.Text = "Check new user"
$UserButton.Add_Click({
    $global:acns = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter account name", "Finalise new account", "atsi")
    if ($acns) { 
        #the get-mailbox query does not work if it get's valid output. if for example i put a query with no result or no valid results i get an error message.
        Get-Mailbox -Identity "$acns" 
    }
        else {
        Write-Host "No input given" 
        }
    })
#    else { Write-Host "$acns" }})
$objForm.Controls.Add($UserButton)

#Cancel button
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,160)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

write-host $acns
```

When I put "Get-Mailbox -Identity $acns" at the end of the script it works as intended. but not when I put in the add_click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI applications doesn't have a console, so the usual "throw every non-saved object to the console" doesn't apply. You need to specify that it should go the the console with ex. `Out-Default`, `Out-Host` (which Out-Default sends to), or convert to string and show that, ex.

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "$acns" | Out-Default
Get-Mailbox -Identity "$acns" | Out-Host
#Since you're still in the GUI-application you won't be able to use the output anyways, so you might as well print it as a string
Get-Mailbox -Identity "$acns" | Out-String | Write-Host
```

Remember: The commands still work and objects can be piped to `Set-Mailbox` etc. It's just the console output that need special attention. I would recommend using the GUI for user output or skip the GUI completely/close it on click and let the console show the rest. Mixing is just messy.

Comment: I think it is not because of GUI, but because of cast to delegate with `void` return type. `([Action]{Write-Output Test}).Invoke()`.

Comment: I'm no developer so I won't argue about the logic behind. :-) However, how does that help me or him? Is there another type of EventHandler you could use with the click-event which returns objects? Anyways, as long as your stuck on the `ShowDialoge()`-function until the form is closed, it doesn't really matter if you get the object out or not, as you won't be able to process it further in the pipeline anyways, so object vs text doesn't really matter.

Comment: OK, it does not really matter if it `void` delegate or not, because delegate return value will be returned to caller of that delegate, not to PowerShell pipeline. But you are not right, it is possible to pipe and process objects in the pipeline, even while you stuck in `ShowDialoge()` method.

Comment: Yes, inside the `Action`, but as I wrote in the updated answer, that already works in his script. :-)

Comment: You can process in pipeline outside of `Action`. Like `FunctionWhichCallShowDialog | ProcessItemsWhileYouStuckInShowDialog`.

Comment: And how would that work considering the script are not going past `ShowDialog()` until it returns (form closed), and the return type is `DialogResult`? Getting warnings to move to chat here, hehe.

Comment: That is how PowerShell pipeline works. `process` block of next pipeline command work inside `WriteObject` call. It does not matter if you inside some other method (like `ShowDialog()`) or not. Although, if you inside some other method, then you need a reference to `PSCmdlet` instance attached to right pipeline and you need to call `WriteObject` by yourself to pipe items in right place. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/PetSerAl/eb829e62801d07ada110) demonstrating that.

Comment: Using the line "Get-Mailbox -Identity "$acns" | Out-String | Write-Host" fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for the tip about `$PSCmdlet`. That has passed by me unnoticed some reason! Learn something new every day:-) @Andry Glad i could help